# How do I run symfony console?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Everywhere I look in the Symfony documentation for Symfony 4.2, it says that to clear the cache, I run:

php bin/console cache:clear

However, this bin/console is a relative path. I can't find bin/console anywhere. I've done a find on my composer vendor directory. Nothing.

Where is bin/console?

I'm running php 7.2.

Comment: the `bin` folder is in root project folder, should be created automatically while setting up the Symfony project

Comment: That's not the case for me. What have I failed to do in setting up the project?

Comment: Tell how you did try to set it up:) Here is a complete guide https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html, did you try it?

Comment: Well, we shoved Symfony into an existing project to manage some APIs. I'll try that guide and see if I can grab bin/console, which is all I really need at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony 4.x structures in like this (From [CoderSkills](http://coderskills.b-project.mg/post/tutoriel/decouvrons-ensemble-symfony-4/3))

[image]
If you don't have the same after your installation, remove your project folder and create a new ones by running `composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton myNewProject`

Here is [a guide to start](http://coderskills.b-project.mg/post/tutoriel/decouvrons-ensemble-symfony-4/creer-son-premier-projet-symfony-4/4/) a new Symfony project